# Is const char * different from other pointers?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

So I've been digging into pointers and references recently because they're used constantly in the resources I've been using to learn OpenGL. I've noticed that the `const char *` pointer seems to behave somewhat differently than other pointers. To demonstrate, I've created this test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int i = 2; 
    int *pi;
    //const char c = "hello world"; 
    const char *pc = "hello world";

    pi = &i;

    std::cout << "'hello world' type is " << typeid("hello world").name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "pi is " << pi << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*pi is " << *pi << std::endl;

    std::cout << "pc is " << pc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*pc is " << *pc << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
'hello world' type is char const [12]
pi is 0079FC38
*pi is 2
pc is hello world
*pc is h
```

This result is confusing to me for several reasons. First, the commented out line `const char c = "hello world"` fails completely; why? By looking at the output, we can see that the type associated with "hello world" itself is char const [12]. Interestingly enough, the following line does work. But, the output is not what I would expect when compared with the output associated with the `int` pointer (`pi`). I.e. why when I print `pc` is the output `hello world` and not a memory address? (less important) And then, why when I print `*pc` is the output only the first element of the data contained at that address?

Comment: `const char c = "hello world";` doesnt work, because `const char c` is a single `char` while `"hello world"` is 12 `char`s, for the other confusion see the duplicate

Comment: OT: you are using hungarian notation with your pointers `pi` and `pc`. There's no reason to do this, and it can make your code harder to understand. Please stop. :(

Comment: @Justin I’m sorry, what is the more appropriate notation?

Comment: @JoshWiens In hungarian notation, you prefix the variable name with type information. In this case, the entire variable name `pi` is "pointer to int" and `pc` is "pointer to char". The preferred style is to actually *name* your variables, and to not worry about encoding the type of the variable into the name. For a trivial example like this, there may not be a reasonable name.

Comment: `unsigned char *` have special exemptions from strict type aliasing rules. The same is true for `char*` since c++17. In that regard, they are special.

Comment: @justin Oh I see what you’re saying now. I don’t use anything like that in actual projects just for simple test stuff like this.

Comment: @justin wouldn't the same arguments  make variable names such as i (integer), c,   str (string), is (input stream)  as representatives-of-Hungarian-notation-to-be-banned as well ?  Wouldn't [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Examples) only start when there's a systematic use of a type **prefix COMBINED with a name** (something like iCounter, strName, isSource, piMinimum) ? It seems to me that here, it's only obvious names for the example

Comment: @Christophe Yes. I was making an oversimplification, as the OP seems relatively new. I've been seeing several questions posted over the past few days with variable names using hungarian notation, and I wanted to say something to help prevent its misuse

Comment: @Justin: For a small test program like this, the variables have no particular meaning other than their types. In that context (but *not* in production code), calling a pointer to `int` `pi` is IMHO perfectly reasonable, and better than, for example, `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, pointers to `const char *` don't work different from other pointers.

What is different in your code is how C++ output streams (specifically) handle a `const char *` versus how they handle other pointers.   It does this by providing distinct overloads of `operator<<()`.

One overload takes a `const char *` as an argument, which is ASSUMED to point at a nul terminated array of `char` (which is how a string literal like `"Hello World"` is represented in memory) and outputs every `char` until that nul is reached.

The other overload accepts a `void *`, and simply outputs the value (i.e. an address).   This relies on implicit conversion of pointer types to `void *`.

So it is not the `const char *` that behaves differently from other pointers.   It is the fact that C++ output streams handle a `const char *` differently from other pointers (by providing distinct overloads that do different things).

Note: Strictly speaking, if you want to print the addresses, you should do

```
std::cout << "pi is " << (void *)pi << std::endl;
std::cout << "pc is " << (void *)pc << std::endl;
```

which will treat both pointers the same way (i.e. print the addresses, not the data at those addresses) since the two pointers are then printed using the same version of `operator<<()`.

Comment: Why cast `pi` to a `void*`? It doesn't make any difference. I also think that for `pc`, a `static_cast` would be a better idea than a C-style cast

Comment: Essentially, my reason is consistency, and making the conversion explicit.   Gives an additional visual cue that the intent is to print an address rather than (say) printing `*pi`.   Purely stylistic and subjective, I admit.    Fair call on use of `static_cast<void *>(pi)`.

Answer (score 1):

The type `char *` is (very) often used to represent "unmanaged strings", i.e. a sequence of characters terminated by a `'\0'`-character (in contrast to class `std::string`, which wraps such an "unmanaged" string). So `cout` takes care of this common usage in that it provides an overload for type `char *`, which treats the value not as a memory address but as a pointer to a sequence of characters.
But this is just (ordinary) function overloading, and - besides some special treatment concerning alignment - there is no difference between a pointer to a char and a pointer to an int.

Answer (score 0):

> First, the commented out line `const char c = "hello world"` fails
>   completely; why? By looking at the output, we can see that the type
>   associated with "hello world" itself is char const [12]

Because an array is not the same as a single object. You cannot initialise an `int` with an `int const[12]`, either.

> why when I print `pc` is the output hello world and not a memory address?

`std::cout` is an object of type `std::ostream`, and that is an instantiation of the `std::basic_ostream` template class, which has a member `operator<<` function for `void const*`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt (overload 7)

The function allows every pointer to be printed as an address, because every pointer can be converted to `void const*`. This overload is therefore chosen for your `int*`.

`char const*` is special because `std::basic_ostream` also has **overloaded non-member `operator<<`** functions for various `char*` variations, one of which take precedence in your example:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2

The overloaded non-member `operator<<` for `char const*` expects the pointer to point to the first character of a null-terminated character array and performs the output operation accordingly.

As you can see, it's the library which makes `char const*` different from other pointers in this particular situation, and not the core language.

> And then, why when I print `*pc` is the output only the first element
>   of the data contained at that address?

Because `*pc` yields a `char` and not a pointer, so a different overload of the non-member `operator<<` is chosen.

If `operator<<` actually took a `char&` *and* took the address of the `char` in order to treat it like a null-terminated character array, chaos would ensue; a simple thing like `std::cout << 'X';` would result in undefined behaviour.

You might argue that there's the same problem in the opposite direction:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c = 'X';
    char cc = 'Y'; // for more astonishing effect in practice, especially
                   // when compiled without optimisation

    std::cout << &c; // undefined behaviour
}
```

And it's true; such bugs can happen. But I'd say the usefulness of being able to write `std::cout << "Hello world";` outweighs the costs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. POINTERS CAN BE REALLY CONFUSING AT TIMES WHERE YOU DON'T EXPECT THEM TO BE.

Now, for the first problem.

`const char c = "hello world"`. In this line `c` is a variable of type `char` and what you are assigning it with is a `string` (hello world). So, it will fail.

Second,

`*pi` will give you the value of the variable which `pi` is pointing to, but in case of `char *`, `*pc` gives the value of the first character in the string of characters (that means in "hello world" `*pc` points to the first character in the string).

If you do `pc[1]` it will give you the second character in the string of characters,but`pc` denotes the whole string.

Comment: *In this line `c` is a variable of type `char`* - no, type `char const`. *"And what you are assigning it with is a `string`."* - no, not a `string`, because that looks like `std::string`, and it's certainly not a `std::string`. Please don't use code format tags for emphasis.